# Database Table Schema Circular Reference issue

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2008, schema

Trying to fix a Circular Reference in a schema created by a developer, but having a hard time.  This is as far as I have gotten. The black line is the tables that are needed to create a file.  The red lines are a second path to the same data.  They are over rides for each of the tables.  The Developer needs a relationship to the CaseFileDefinition and the table field that is being over ridden so the processor code knows which over ride goes to which client when processing files.

My question is, because I set the Over Ride tables as many to many, am I avoiding circular logic? Is there a better way to model over rides to a table?

[image]